# What is the first vector to be read by the compiler in a vector addition operation in C?

Tags: c, caching, memory, vector

I am analyzing the operation of the cache of a code and this question has arisen:

```
C[i] = B[i] + A[i];
G[i] = x*F[i];
```

This is the part of the code where I have the doubt. Context: my cache memory has space up to 4 of these 5 vectors. It works with a LRU algorithm (Least Recently Used) so C,B,A and F are stored with any problem, but G has no space in the cache so the vector that has not been used for the longest time is replaced with the vector values of G. Here are the questions:

Was A the first or was it B? What principle does the C compiler follow to make the decision of what element is first read? Does it depend on which compiler is used (GCC, ICC...) or do they all generally follow the same discipline?

Comment: what does "vector" mean in this context? SSE? array?

Comment: Vector array, just a simple 1024 length array created with calloc() and filled with some data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `C[i] = B[i] + A[i];` the compiler may load `A[i]` first or `B[i]` first. The C standard does not impose any requirement on this ordering.

With `G[i] = x*F[i];` coming after that, the compiler must load `F[i]` after storing `C[i]` unless it can determine that `F[i]` is not the same object as `C[i]`. If it can determine that, then it may load `A[i]`, `B[i]`, and `F[i]` in any order.

Similarly, if it can determine that `G[i]` does not overlap `C[i]`, it may store `C[i]` and `G[i]` in either order.

If this code appears in a loop, this permissive reordering extends to elements between iterations of the loop: If the compiler can determine that it will not affect the defined results, it can load `B[i]` from a “future” iteration before it loads `A[i]` for the current iteration, for example. It could load four elements from `B`, four elements from `A`, four elements from `F`, and do all the arithmetic before it stores any elements to `C` or `G`. (Often the compiler does not have the necessary information that the arrays overlap, so it will not do this reordering unless you give it that information in some way, as by declaring the pointers with `restrict` or use special pragmas or compiler built-ins to tell it these things.)

Generally, the C standard is permissive about how actual operations are ordered. It only mandates that the observable behavior it specifies be satisfied. You should not expect that any particular elements are loaded first based on standard C code alone.

Comment: I didn't spect that, thought that it had an standard. Thank you for helping me.